# Quartz.Net - simple trigger scenarios

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I'm currently in process of selecting a framework for building a scheduling system.
It is quite simple (so i thought) it seems however that I can't get some scenarios to work with Quartz.

1. **Every 4 weeks on Mon,Tue,Wed** - been told that I can use cron to trigger every week and check somehow the counter - it doesnt seem very ideal.
2. **Day 3 of every 5 months** - would it be (* * * 3 0/5 * *) ?
3. **The third Monday of every 3 months** - I know I can use `L` for last not sure how to do `first, second, third, fourth/last`

I have so far been happy with all my other scenarios and it seems that Quartz.NET is a way to go, I just have to make sure that all my scenarios are possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) looks like it may be able to help you out.

Comment: one more thing though... sort of another question really. Is there any way of setting up end date. ie. run 5 times or run until 2011/09/05

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure about Quatz.net but in Java Quartz when you build a trigger you can specify end time. With [setEndTime](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html#setEndTime(java.util.Date)) method